# Get data from one table filtering it by other table in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

**Table 1**:

```
userid name
1      Dharam
2      James
3      Ramesh
4      David
```

**Table 2**:

```
follower(id) following(id)
1            2
2            1
2            3
3            4
```

Here, I have **Table 1** for all users and **Table 2** for who is following whom.

I want to get result as

> Show the users from **'Table 1'** WHERE **'Table 1'** users should not be already following the same person

Means, Get users whom **user 1** is not following FROM **Table 1** filtered by **Table 2**

**Result**:

```
3
4
```

Comment: Another Twitter-like problem? Search SO there are several similar questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: inner query

```
SELECT * from users WHERE user_id NOT IN (
               SELECT user_id_foreign_key FROM follow_details)
```

Comment: **Thank You**, for Your answer. But, I want every users except the users whom one user is following. But your query is giving the user who is not following anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with a `join`:

```
 SELECT t1.userid, t2.follower
 FROM tbl1 AS t1 
      LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON t1.userid = t2.follower
 HAVING follower IS NOT NULL
```